# jqueryUI - slide hander getting wrong position..

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

After i made a sample slider work, i made the handler to custom height. but in the top side it's getting hide and the bottom it's move out.

just any one can help to "what is the correct way to re-size the handler ?"

my code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#sample').slider({orientation:'vertical'});
});​
```

css:

```
.ui-slider {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 2em;
    background: #CCC;
    margin-left:50px;
}
.ui-slider-handle.ui-state-default {
    display: block;
    cursor: move;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-top:0.2em;
    background: #333
}​
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Erugp/93/)